# ORM joins not workinng after upgrading Laravel App to 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I upgraded my laravel 5.0 to 5.3 . After that ORM joins is not working at all. Is there any suggestions why it is not working ?
I followed all the insructions form 
[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade)

But it looks like I missed something due to which joins not working, joins code is correct and it was working prior upgrade.
Code :

```
 public function CompanyDataGet() 
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model','id','othertable_id'); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `belongsTo` means the **inverse** relationship.

## What says Laravel's API?

The most common way is to check the API of Laravel 5.3 (https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_belongsTo):

```
BelongsTo belongsTo(string $related, string $foreignKey = null, string $otherKey = null, string $relation = null)
```

## Solution

By default, only the `$related` is required:

```
public function CompanyDataGet() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model'); 
}
```

If you still want to pass the key names (for example, if you are using non-default names):

- The **second** argument should be the **foreign key**!
- The **third** argument should be the **local key**!

Your code should be:

```
public function CompanyDataGet() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model', 'othertable_id', 'id'); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs @schellingerht .  Problem is all you mentioned was working before upgrading to laravel 5.3 . Suddenly it stopped working after upgrade. I have read all things you mentioned from official docs. I need someone who have upgraded Laravel earlier and face that kind of issue.

Comment: Ok, I'm that 'someone' ;-). But, it's important to make your code correct, whatever your first code was. Comparing the documentation, you should turn the key params.